# Adding layer names to combobox in QGIS plugin - layer names appear more than once

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am creating an OGIS plugin, but I have a problem. I want the layers in the problem layer panel to automatically appear in the ComboBox. I wrote the necessary code for this, but when I open the plugin every new layer, each layer in the layer panel appears twice, how can I fix this?
Code written:

```
Layers = self.iface.legendInterface().Layers()
Layer_list = []
For layer in layers:
      Layer_list.append (layer.name())
      self.dlg.comboBox.addItems(layer_list)
```

Comment: Please do not use ALL CAPS in question titles. You can fix that by using the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it.

Comment: have you tried **[self.dlg.comboBox.clear()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#clear)** ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't write your own code for this - instead use the provided QgsMapLayerComboBox widget, which automatically handles populating the combo box and updating it if the map layers change. QgsMapLayerComboBox also supports filtering by numerous parameters so you can tweak which layers will be shown in the combo box.

Answer (score 0):

ndawson is right. For the map layers use QgsMapLayerComboBox.

To avoid duplicate items in other cases you can use `set()`.

I use this in the case of choosing users:

```
userList = set([username.title(), 'User1', 'User2'])
for f in userList :
    self.user.addItem( f )
```

`username.title` is the actual Windows User (1st letter is uppercase) and is always either User1 or User2.